# What is: udisks-error-quark,14

Tags: partitioning, windows-10, filemanager, disk-management

I want to delete data partition, but I cant do that. what can i du with:   udisks-error-quark,14

Comment: Please [edit](https://askubuntu.com/posts/1272514/edit) your question and write exact steps you did in it to make problem reproducible.

Comment: If the partition is mounted then unmount it and try again